# Convert adjacency matrix to a distance or hop matrix

Tags: c, matlab, linear-algebra, adjacency-matrix, distance-matrix

Is it possible to convert an ***adjacency matrix*** of ones and zeros as defined  [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix#Examples) into a ***distance matrix*** as defined [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_matrix#Examples_and_uses)  where each link would be of unit length 1?

Comment: Do you have informations about the weight of each link?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An adjacency matrix of ones and zeros is simply a representation of an undirected graph. To get the distances between any two vertices of an unweighted graph, you can use [breadth first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search).

Assuming you have an `n` by `n` matrix:

```
for each vertex i:
    initialize an nxn matrix M
    run breadth-first search starting at i
    copy distances into row i of M
    return M
```

Comment: Instead of breadth first search, it would probably be better to use an algorithm for the [all-pairs shortest-path problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem)

Comment: this will take forever for a large case

Comment: @Hans: Floyd-Warshall takes `O(V^3)` time whereas BFS takes `O(V^2+VE)`. BFS is always faster, and significantly more so for sparse graphs. The fastest way of finding the shortest path in an undirected graph is always BFS.

Comment: @tskuzzy: what's V and E? Number of nodes/edges? Here, distances between all pairs are needed, as far as I understand it BFS only finds the distance to the root node - can you elaborate on that? Also, in real life constants actually matter...

Comment: @Hans: Yes, V is the number of vertices and E is the number of edges. We run a BFS for each vertex, so that calculates the all-pairs shortest path. The constants associated with BFS are comparable to that of FW, if not smaller. If you benchmark the two, you would see BFS is superior.

Comment: both good points i ended up having to use Dijkstra's algorithm with Fibonacci heaps from an implementation i found on the web