# C/C++ Best algorithm to perfom Adjacency2Distance matrix [Solved by Floyd-Warshall]

Tags: c, algorithm

```
INITIAL ISSUE
```

Good day everybody,

I've already found several algorithms to do this task. The but is that all those codes consider a weight value per node or edge.

My aim is easier than that, It is to get the distance matrix from adjacency one.

The input would be:

```
  a b c d e f    connected vertices to i
a 0 1 0 0 0 0    1
b 1 0 1 1 0 0    3
c 0 1 0 0 0 0    1
d 0 1 0 0 1 0    2
e 0 0 0 1 0 1    2
f 0 0 0 0 1 0    1
                ---
            Sum: 10  -> Edges = Sum/2 = 5
```

The output would be:

```
  a b c d e f
a 0 1 2 2 3 4
b 1 0 1 1 2 3
c 2 1 0 2 3 4
d 2 1 2 0 1 2
e 3 2 3 1 0 1
f 4 3 4 2 1 0
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestion,

David Alejandro.

```
SOLUTION FOUND
```

Floyd-Warshall Kernell in C

```
for (k = 0; k < n; ++k) 
{
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; ++j)
        {
            if ((dist[i][k] * dist[k][j] != 0) && (i != j))
            {
                if ((dist[i][k] + dist[k][j] < dist[i][j]) || (dist[i][j] == 0))
                {
                    dist[i][j] = dist[i][k] + dist[k][j];
                }
            }
        }
    }                   
}
```

Comment: Perhaps duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10079876/converting-a-adjacency-matrix-to-a-distance-or-hop-matrix

Comment: Theoretical best so far seems to be `O(n² log n)` (see http://www.waset.org/journals/ijcms/v3/v3-5-43.pdf), but I can't really understand it.

Comment: (: Gracias... 'Tanta' Marcha...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've already found algorithms to do it only with weight associations, use them, but set every weight to 1.

[BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) would be my suggestion in any case.

Comment: Good suggestion. For basic needs, best way is going deep!

Answer (score 1):

Change zeros for an "infinite" (i.e. larger than any reasonable distance) value in your adjacency matrix and then run [Floyd-Warshall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) on the resulting matrix.

BFS as suggested by NominSim would need to be run from each starting vertex in order to get you distances for *all* vertices.

Comment: BFS n times -> O(mn + n²). Floyd-Warshall is far easier to code, though.

Comment: But O(mn) with an adjacency matrix is O(n^3) so they're both O(n^3). In any case, I wasn't comparing efficiency, I was just stating that plain BFS only solves single-source shortest paths, whereas the OP asks for all-pairs.